# Image View Does not display image after setting image to it downloaded from url

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

here it is what i am doing.

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = image
            }
            }.resume()
    }
    func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
```

i checked it in image its show image in preview in debug state. but after `self.image = image`

nothing change on image view image is not displaying. anyone know where the problem is ? thanks

Comment: Remove this -> `DispatchQueue.main.async()`. UI changes always be done in the main thread not in async. and remove guard too, half your code in guard or half in else.

Comment: i use gaurd to avoid crash if value is nil :(

Comment: and by removing  dispatchQueue.main.async i got this warning 

UIImageView.image must be used from main thread only

Comment: remove error == nil on guard line. and try again download image.

Comment: Please share us the image URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most efficient way for downloading image: [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

You can use a Cocoa Pod file for SDWebImage Library.

1. init the pod file.
2. pod 'SDWebImage'
3. install Pod file.

Swift snippet:

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: @"user-url"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
```

Objective-C Snippet:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
...
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"user-url"]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

Hope this will help to do efficient way to downloading images basically, whenever you are using UICollectionView or UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easier with Kingfisher library like below.

```
let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

Comment: same issue with this library to .. :/

Comment: Could you share image url?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
 if data != nil { // check nil here

                        let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                        self.image = image
                    }
                    }
    }.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to check the image mime type, just a check of data and image is sufficient, since data will be nil for error and vice versa.

change as

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = image
        }
    }.resume()
```

And cross check with image with debugger.